# Unable to play YouTube videos on embed

Tags: reactjs, youtube

I have a component which loads embedded YouTube video as below

```
const url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/'${videoId}`;

<iframe className="embed-responsive-item" src={url}></iframe>
```

But it's showing black screen and if click on the play button, it's showing

> An error occured. Please try again later. (Playback ID: ZrAX.....) Learn More

And if clicking on `Learn More` link, the issues listed is all about below, which none of them are helpful

> An error has occurred.
>
> Playback error. Tap to retry.
>
> Connection to server lost.
>
> This video is unavailable.
>
> Something went wrong. Tap to Retry.

[image]

Comment: The `'` shouldn't be there.

Comment: omg @tkausl yes! I was scratching my head figuring what went wrong. I will close the question now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the ' from the link, so it should just be:
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`

Comment: I have the same issue for this code:  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nLixe-efBRg" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

Check the ID of your YouTube video and use only its ID — after the "v=". **Do not** add the whole string that comes after the "youtube.com" from your link. Let's say you have a YouTube video with the following link : https://youtube.com/watch?v=1ahcHcgdgyQ; the ID of your video start after the "v="; in this case, the video ID is: 1ahcHcgdgyQ **not** watch?v=1ahcHcgdgyQ

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).